# SherlockDialogFragment onCreateView that needs a created activity

Tags: android-activity, android-dialogfragment

How to handle situations where a custom `SherlockDialogFragment` onCreateView() needs the activity to build its view?
More specifically, needs the activity onCreate() method to be executed before building its view. The custom `SherlockDialogFragment` is EffectSettingsDialog.
I can always reproduce the exception (that i mentioned in the comment section) in the emulator (tested with api level 10).
When the dialog is shown if I press ctrl-f11 (or ctrl-f12) the app crashes.
The app is thought to work in landscape mode (so I set android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the app manifest).

EffectSettingsDialog.java

```
/**
 * 
 * @author
 *
 */
public class EffectSettingsDialog extends SherlockDialogFragment
{
    final   static  String  DIALOG_TAG = "effect_settings_dialog";


    final           int     UNKNOWN_BUTTON = 0;
    final           int     OK_BUTTON = 1;
    final           int     CANCEL_BUTTON = 2;
    final           int     RESET_BUTTON = 3;
    int             pressed_button = UNKNOWN_BUTTON;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public EffectSettingsDialog( )
    {
        super();

        CLog.i( "EffectSettingsDialog", "EffectSettingsDialog()" );
    }




     /**
     * Create a new instance of WelcomeDialog.
     */
    static EffectSettingsDialog newInstance()
    {
        EffectSettingsDialog d = new EffectSettingsDialog();

        return d;
    }   


    /**
     * 
     */
    static  boolean showNewInstance( FragmentActivity   activity, int   fx_id )
    {       
        if ( fx_id == -1 )
            return  false;

        Fragment prev = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( EffectSettingsDialog.DIALOG_TAG );      
        if (prev != null)
            return  false;
        EffectSettingsDialog    d = EffectSettingsDialog.newInstance();

        // Supply fx_id parameter to the fragment
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt( "fx_id", fx_id );
        d.setArguments(args);

        d.show( activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), EffectSettingsDialog.DIALOG_TAG );        
        return  true;
    }






    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
    {
        CLog.i( "EffectSettingsDialog", "onCreate()" );
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int style = SherlockDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE;     
        int theme = getTheme();
        setStyle(style, theme );//, theme);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle ) 
    {
        CLog.i( "EffectSettingsDialog", "onCreateDialog()" );
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dialog  d = super.onCreateDialog( savedInstanceStateBundle );       
        return  d;  
    }


    @Override
    public  View    onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {   
        CLog.i( "EffectSettingsDialog", "onCreateView()" );

        /// Here i need to call  ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getData() to properly initialize the view. Initialization code omitted...


        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource( R.color.transparent );//translucent_black );
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND );

        return v;
    }

}
```

In the activity (in the onClick() method), i use the following code:

```
EffectSettingsDialog.showNewInstance( this, fx_id );
```

This happens when the user touches a specific button.

Comment: It seems to me that the method DialogFragment.onActivityCreated() is called after the onCreate() method of the activity, but DialogFragment.onCreateView() in not guaranteed to be called after onCreate().

Comment: This dialog fragment is showed when the user touches a button on the activity view. So the activity is obviously already created. But i had an exception of this type when launching the app: "android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment MyCustomDialogFragment: make sure class name  exists, is public and has an empty constructor that is public". I do not know why MyCustomDialogFragment was needed to start the activity, but anyhow i can't create the view of the dialog fragment if the onCreate() method of the activity has not been already called.